# How to modify color when scale_colour_manual does nothing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter plot which will be generated by a search of a specific protein. The results will be an exact match(maybe), partial match(maybe) and no matches.

So a typical result set would be, 1 match, 3 partial, 6396 no match. All of these 6400 proteins have a foldChange and pvalue associated with them. I need to get these 3 categories into different colors, no match being a #878282, match #0072B2, and partial match #BC2B2B. The issue I have is that `scale_colour_manual` doesn't modify the colors regardless of the values i add. At least its not doing it for me in R, or when i run the robject in django. Here is part of the plot code.

```
colmapping <- unique(data_source[c('labels','colors')])
    plot<-ggplot(data_source, aes(x=foldChange, y=pvalues, col=factor(labels)))+
        scale_colour_manual(breaks=colmapping$labels, values= colmapping$colors)+   
        scale_colour_hue(l=40)+
        xlab(xaxis)+ylab(yaxis)+
        geom_point()+    
        scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 4))+
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-5, 5), breaks=c(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5))+
        theme_bw()+
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14, vjust=-0.4))+
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, angle=90))+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10))+
        theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=10))
```

I can change the colors by originally setting the `geom_point` grey and if matches are detected modify it, however that would not give me a legend explaining what is what.

Any insight into why this is occurring or how to fix it to achieve the formerly mentioned results would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have two colour scales in your plot, the second one presumably overwrites `scale_manual`

Comment: you are correct, that was rather unintelligent of my part. That solved the issue, much thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, crossed posts with my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding two color scales. If you were to type the code directly into R, you'd get the following message:

```
Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale.
```

`scale_color_hue` and `scale_color_manual` are both ways of specifying how ggplot should assign colors to different categories. First you are specifying that the colors should be taken from your `colmapping` frame, and then saying "no, actaully, scrap that, create a scale based on hue with lightness=40".

Your `scale_color_hue(l=40)` is overwritting your `scale_colour_manual(breaks = ...`, you should only use one of them. From your post I think you just want the `scale_color_manual`.